# extending the execution time of jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have couple of `<img>` thumbnails on a page (wrapped in `<a>` and `<li>` tags). I am highlighting thumbnails on hover by increasing padding and changing bg color of the `<li>`s, using jQuery.

```
<div id='film_container'>
   <ul>                     //echoing through php loop
      <a href='#'>
         <li class='film_list'> 
            <img class='poster' src='$poster_small'/>
            <span>$film_name</span>
         </li>
      </a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('li.film_list').hover(function(){
         $(this).css("padding","2%");
         $(this).css("background-color","#A8383B");}, 
      function(){
         $(this).css("padding","");
         $(this).css("background-color","");
      });
    });
</script>
```

This code is working fine, but transitions on hover are happening too quickly and appear jittery. I'd like it to slow down. I tried `delay()`, but it didn't seem to work. I want the padding increase to be less noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to go with CSS:

```
.film_list {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.film_list:hover {
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #A8383B;
}
```

### Demo:

```css
.film_list {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.film_list:hover {
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #A8383B;
}

ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<div id='film_container'>
    <ul>
        <li class='film_list'>
            <a href="">
                <img class='poster' src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1' />
                <span>Travis and Biver</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Snippets are underrated

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yeah, 0 in this whole question.

Comment: Well I would love to use stacksnippets for the demo, unfortunately they don't work for me, just don't insert in the post. So I have to go with old jsfiddle way.

Comment: @dfsq I edited in the snippet manually for you. This bug has [already been reported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272736/cannot-create-stack-snippet) on meta and should be fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you. Another poor thing about this snippets that it's not editable in popup once inserted. Also it's not possible to hide say HTML part only. To me all this make stacksnippets pretty limited and less convenient then even fiddle. For more complex examples like for Angular demos it makes no sense at all to use Stacksnippets, as Plunkr beats them completely in all senses. But for simple CSS examples they can be useful.

Comment: @dfsq They can be edited in the editor, actually. While editing the answer, look for the "edit the above snippet" link in the rendered preview.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend CSS3 to do it:

```
.film_list{
    padding: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    transition: padding .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.film_list:hover{
    padding: 2%;
    background-color:#A8383B;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1g24thj/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS may be the way to go as others have pointed out but if you're looking to only modify the code you already have, you can use `setTimeout`. Note the 2nd parameter to `setTimeout` is the number of milliseconds to wait before the function is called, so you can change that to whatever you want. Also, if you want the delay to happen on hover as well, you can add the same functionality there.

```
$('li.film_list').hover(function () {
    $(this).css("padding", "2%");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#A8383B");
}, function () {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.css("padding", "");
        self.css("background-color", "");
    }, 1000);
});
```

**[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf9uovzk/).**

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to stick to the code you have with some minor modifications, I'd suggest using jquerys `animate()`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqe2cgmx/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.film_list').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({'padding' : '2%'}, "slow");
        $(this).css("background-color","#A8383B");}, function(){
        $(this).animate({'padding' : '0'}, "slow");
        $(this).css("background-color","");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.film_list').hover(
      function(){$(this).animate({padding:"2%",backgroundColor:"#A8383B"}, 500);},
      function(){$(this).animate({padding:"0",backgroundColor:"#FFF"}, 500);}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using jquery - you can use animate to achieve your desired results:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id='film_container'>
            <ul>
                <a href='#'>
                    <li class='film_list'> 
                        <img class='poster' src='$poster_small'/>
                        <span>$film_name</span>
                    </li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("li.film_list").hover(function () {
                    $(this).filter(":not(:animated)").animate({
                        padding: "2%"
                    }, "slow");
                    $(this).css("background-color","#A8383B");
                }, function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        padding: "0"
                    }, "slow");
                    $(this).css("background-color","");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ffL1swzy/